# How to efficiently use docker cache if the source path of a file is different but destination and content is the same?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an issue with docker caching: When I have two docker files

File 1

```
FROM base

COPY path/1/file tmp/
```

File 2

```
FROM base

COPY path/2/file tmp/
```

If both files are the same, the layers are still different because of the different source path. Is there any way the build for File 2 can use the cache from File 1 so it does not have to redo the build (after the copy step come expensive operations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because the command is different from the other file.

From Docker docs:

> Starting with a parent image that is already in the cache, the next instruction is compared against all child images derived from that base image to see if one of them was built **using the exact same instruction**. If not, the cache is invalidated.

and

> Once the cache is invalidated, all subsequent Dockerfile commands generate new images and the cache is not used.

[Docker Cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache)

So, everything you execute below your "new" command, we''l be a new generated layer.